# DataGridView Masked TextBox Column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, maskedtextbox

I have a DataGridView with  2 columns,and i wanted to create some kind of input mask to it. So i found a small class that inherits maskedtextbox control and lets you use it in a datagridview. Everything works fine,the mask works as intended, no big deal. heres the library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox

My problem is,once the row has all the data i need,pressing enter or tab does not create a new row, even tho i have datagridview1.AllowUserToAddRows = true.
Then i found out the problem was in the library i linked,because when i add a simple datagrid textbox,pressing enter or tab does create a new row.

so i added this routine,to hopefully create a new row when i am on the last column of the last row:

```
private void dgOre_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.RowIndex== dgOre.Rows.Count-1 && e.ColumnIndex== dgOre.Columns.Count - 1){
            dgOre.Rows.Add();
    }
}
```

the problem with this routine is that it does add a row,but it creates it BEFORE the last row,creating a gap,as if i am creating a row before some other event is launched. I should change something in the maskedtextbox library, or use a different event,but i have no idea how and what to edit.

Here is the source code of editing control:

```
public class DataGridViewMaskedTextEditingControl : MaskedTextBox, 
    IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    #region Fields
    private DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged;
    private int rowIndex;
    #endregion
    #region Constructor
    public DataGridViewMaskedTextEditingControl()
    {
        Mask = String.Empty;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Interface's properties
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get { return dataGridView; }
        set { dataGridView = value; }
    }
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set
        {
            if (value is string)
                Text = (string)value;
        }
    }
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get { return rowIndex; }
        set { rowIndex = value; }
    }
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get { return valueChanged; }
        set { valueChanged = value; }
    }
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get { return base.Cursor; }
    }
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Interface's methods
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        //  get the current cell to use the specific mask string
        DataGridViewMaskedTextCell cell
            = dataGridView.CurrentCell as DataGridViewMaskedTextCell;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            Mask = cell.Mask;
        }
    }
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        //  Note: In a DataGridView, one could prefer to change the row using
        //  the up/down keys.
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        if (selectAll)
            SelectAll();
        else
        {
            SelectionStart = 0;
            SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region MaskedTextBox event
    protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        EditingControlValueChanged = true;
        if (EditingControlDataGridView != null)
        {
            EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = Text;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The main problem is in `DataGridViewMaskedTextEditingControl` class, in `OnTextChanged` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a change is made in your editing control, you should notify the grid of changes using [`NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.notifycurrentcelldirty(v=vs.110).aspx) of the grid. So you can write such code in your editing control:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    EditingControlValueChanged = true;
    EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot. i'lll test it out tomorrow as i am out of work,but this one should be the solution

Comment: I believe the library needs more fixes, for example `(string)Value` in `InitializeEditingControl` in `DataGridViewMaskedTextCell` class is totally wrong. `Value.ToString()` is better. The more correct way is `var str = initialFormattedValue as string;` and then `if (str==null) str = string.Empty;` and then use `editingControl.Text = str;`

Comment: The library has some obvious problems,but its good enough for my needs. I managed to make some more tests,and your fix does work so i marked it as accepted,thanks a lot for your help