# DataGridViewMaskedTextBoxCell OnLeaveEvent exception error

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, maskedtextbox

I found some code in this [link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?429289-Help-Added-MaskedTextBox-to-the-DataGridView-control) that i need in my project. This custom control being edited from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells) `DateTimePicker`. I tried to edit this custom `DataGridViewMaskedTextBoxCell` but without success. Finally i found some error `Exception` after i modify `OnLeave` event of `MaskedTextBox`. Here is the `code`:

```
public class MaskedTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    public MaskedTextBoxCell()
    : base()
    {
    }
    public string Mask { get; set; }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
    initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
            MaskedTextBoxEditingControl ctl =
            DataGridView.EditingControl as MaskedTextBoxEditingControl;
            //ctl.Mask = "00000-000-00000-0";
            //ctl.Text = (string)this.Value;
            ctl.Mask = Mask;
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(MaskedTextBoxEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(MaskedTextBox);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            return "00000-000-00000-0";
        }
    }
}
public class MaskedTextBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public MaskedTextBoxColumn()
    : base(new MaskedTextBoxCell())
    {
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null &&
            !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MaskedTextBoxCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a MaskedTextBoxCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
class MaskedTextBoxEditingControl : MaskedTextBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public MaskedTextBoxEditingControl()
    {
        this.Mask = "00000-000-00000-0";
    }

    public string MaskFormat
    {
        set
        {
            this.Mask = "00000-000-00000-0";
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue 
    // property.
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is String)
            {
                this.Text = (string)value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Implements the 
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
    DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the 
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
    DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex 
    // property.
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey 
    // method.
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
    Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit 
    // method.
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property.
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingControlValueChanged property.
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingPanelCursor property.
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }

    //protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell
        // have changed.
        valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnLeave(eventargs);
    }
}
```

I call the custom control:

```
MaskedTextBoxCell tb = new MaskedTextBoxCell();
dataGridView1[0, 5] = tb;
tb.Mask = @"\(\0\80)-000-0000";
```

What i need is when `dataGridView` shows for the first time in this particular row, the `Mask` will be `visible` and when i leave the `cell` the text that i enter stays there. But when i changed the `Onleave` event error shows up.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38876167/3110834) also make sure you read comments under my answer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei exception occured in your `OnTextChanged` event      `protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    EditingControlValueChanged = true;
    EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
}`

Comment: @RezaAghaei this method not returning an error in my project `protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            EditingControlValueChanged = true;
            if (EditingControlDataGridView != null)
            {
                EditingControlDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = Text;
            }
        }`