# What keyboard shortcut to be used for Mouse Double Click in Sendkeys.Send()

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to double click the Masked Textbox which is inside datagridview.

But when i try to enter some value after the masked textbox gets focus, I am not able to enter any value. But I can able to enter a value when i double click using mouse. So i checked by writing SendKeys.Send("{F2}") in DataGridView.KeyPress event which works for all the normal columns to edit(like textbox), but not able to enter a value in MaskedTextBox.

Please assist me on the SendKeys.Send() for mouse double click.

In the DataGridView, key press event tried to call sendKeys.send("{F2}").

sendKeys.send("{F2}")

When the Masked textbox inside datagridview comes to focus, user should be able to enter a value.

Below is my sample coding :

```
private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn TpyeCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
   TpyeCol.Name = "Type";
   TpyeCol.HeaderText = "Type";
   TpyeCol.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "Home Phone", "Cell", "Work", "Email" });
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(TpyeCol);
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Description", "Description");
   this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Home Phone","");
   this.maskedTextBox = new MaskedTextBox();
   this.maskedTextBox.Visible = false;
   this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(this.maskedTextBox);
   this.dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += new DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit);
   this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
   this.dataGridView1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(dataGridView1_Scroll);
}

void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.maskedTextBox.Visible)
   {
       Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(                                                  this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex,                    this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, true);
       this.maskedTextBox.Location = rect.Location;
    }
}

void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender,DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Description"].Index &&
       e.RowIndex < this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
   {
       string type = this.dataGridView1["Type",e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
       if (type == "Home Phone" || type == "Cell" || type == "Work")
       {
          this.maskedTextBox.Mask = "00/00/0000";
          Rectangle rect =                      this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex,true);
          this.maskedTextBox.Location = rect.Location;
          this.maskedTextBox.Size = rect.Size;
          this.maskedTextBox.Text = "04/02/2019";
          if (this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
          {
              this.maskedTextBox.Text = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex,
              e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
          }
          this.maskedTextBox.Visible = true;
       }
   }
}

void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (this.maskedTextBox.Visible)
   {
       this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = this.maskedTextBox.Text;
       this.maskedTextBox.Visible = false;
   }
} 

void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, DataGridKeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   If(dataGridView1.ColumnIndex = 1)
   {
      SendKeys.Send("{F2}") //To Point cursor in position 1 of Masked TextBox but not able to edit the masked textbox in DGV
   }
}
MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox;
```

Comment: MDblClick often work as a select-all command. Can you try sending ctl-A ?

Comment: Are you sure you're working at the right level? Using e.g. the UI Automation system lets you work at a *semantic* level, not a *raw* "input events" level.

Comment: Are you implying that this DGV doesn't belong to your application?

Comment: Hi Govindon. I think your question may be improved, by formatting it. Also consider adding a [mcve], as you more likely will get a good answer for your question.

Comment: `F2` means _Edit_. As the cells in the DGV are not editable directly when they're selected `F2` makes them go into _Edit mode_, which **in this case** happens to be the same as a double-click by the left mouse button. A TextBox already is editable by default and therefore doesn't respond to the `F2` key.

Comment: Though if I'm interpreting the situation correctly you appear to have created a custom column type containing a `MaskedTextBox`, right? You might want to show us this implementation so that we can see if there are any issues with it.

Comment: Hi @VisualVincent, Yes!!! I am using custom column type "Masked Text Box". I could able to edit in DGV if i click F2 inside textbox. But I am not able to do the same if my column is "Masked Text Box".

Comment: @VisualVincent, I have written the creation of Masked Text Box in DataGridView Event of CellBeginEdit.

Comment: If you're creating the `MaskedTextBox` on the fly then it's no wonder that it doesn't work. The `MaskedTextBox` is not part of the DGV and therefore doesn't gain focus automatically. We need to see that code to be sure, but you should actually implement _an actual custom column_ rather than faking it like this.

Comment: @VisualVincent, Please have a look at the code which was added and help me out to achieve the focus on MaskedTextBox inside DGV

Comment: @LuckyLikey, added an example code. Please help me out to achieve the focus on MaskedTextBox which is inside DataGridView.

Comment: @VisualVincent, If this can't be achieved, then any other possibilities to achieve the same.

Comment: The easy fix (if it works) is to set focus to the `MaskedTextBox` after `this.maskedTextBox.Visible = true;`, thus: `this.maskedTextBox.Focus();`. However as I said this workaround is error-prone and it's better to implement it as an _actual_ custom column type. If you need to switch between viewing the masked mode or not, then create a custom control containing both a `MaskedTextBox` and another control such as a label. True `MaskedTextBox` column implementations (containing only a `MaskedTextBox`) can be found via some googling, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38876167).

Comment: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells).