# Focus and Double Click problem in a DataGridView cell that contains a MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, maskedtextbox

I have a problem when trying to edit a cell that contains a maskedtextbox:

If I try to edit the field I need to:

1. double click on the cell (on this step the maskedtextbox becomes visible)
2. click on the field again to begin edit
3. set cursor "manually" to maskedtextbox first position

(4. start entering value)

It is possible somehow to avoid "manual" focusing to the maskedtextbox first position? (for example on single or double click : set visible the maskedtextbox and the same time set focus / cursor on the first position for the maskedtextbox )

I tried with: focus(), select(), SelectionStart, CurrentCell but without luck.

I added a MaskedTextbox to a DataGridView cell in the following way:

```
public Insert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.maskedTextBox = new MaskedTextBox();

        this.maskedTextBox.Visible = false;

        this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(this.maskedTextBox);

        this.dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += new DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit);

        this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);

        this.dataGridView1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(dataGridView1_Scroll);
    }

    void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.maskedTextBox.Visible)
        {
            Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex,
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, true);
            this.maskedTextBox.Location = rect.Location;
        }
    }
    void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].Index || e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            string type = "";
            if (this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
                type = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            this.maskedTextBox.Mask = "0000.00.00";
            Rectangle rect =
               this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);

            this.maskedTextBox.Location = rect.Location;
            this.maskedTextBox.Size = rect.Size;
            this.maskedTextBox.Text = "";

            if (this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
            {
                this.maskedTextBox.Text = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex,
                    e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            }
            this.maskedTextBox.Visible = true;
            this.maskedTextBox.Focus(); //tried
            this.maskedTextBox.Select(0, 0);
            this.maskedTextBox.SelectionStart =0 ;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        }
    }
void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
if (this.maskedTextBox.Visible && (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["TEST"].Index && e.RowIndex > -1))
            {
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = maskedTextBox.Text;
                this.maskedTextBox.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try using a custom DataGridView column version. See [DataGridView Masked TextBox Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38876167/719186).

Comment: the problem is: that  this code is used on many forms and the datagridview has other controls too (like combobox controls) that are implemented the same way as the above maskedtextbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control probably needs to get the focus *after* the BeginEdit method is complete, so try it this way:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
  this.maskedTextBox.Visible = true;
  this.maskedTextBox.Focus();
  this.maskedTextBox.Select(0, 0);
}));
```

Comment: perfect answer, it works ! i rewrite a code a bit because I'm using .net 2.0 in VS 2005:                `this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                  this.maskedTextBox.Visible = true;
                  this.maskedTextBox.Focus();
                  this.maskedTextBox.Select(0, 0);
                });` , Thanks very much !